# why macro is creating Leading space while resolving macro in sas?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am submitting the following SAS code:

```
 proc format;
   picture mysdt
   low-high = '%Y%0m%0d%0H%0M' (datatype =datetime);
  run;

 DATA _NULL_;
   call symput("Today", Put(datetime(),mysdt.));
 run;

 %put t_&today;
```

The resulting log shows 2 spaces before the datetime:

```
t_  201504240150
```

The problem here is when my macro is resolved it is creating leading space. Why is it creating spaces?

My output should be:

```
t_201504240150
```

I know the solution but just wanted to know the reason.

```
DATA _NULL_;
  call symput("Today", strip(Put(datetime(),mysdt.)));
run;
```

Comment: Between t_ and 201504240150. I Just wanted to know why is it creating space??

Comment: I don't have the expertise for this, but update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is that your format is set up with a default length of 14. Therefore, when you go to put your value into `&today` it is stored with leading blanks to fill out the length to 14. From the SAS documentation:

> DEFAULT=length
>
> specifies the default length of the picture. The value for DEFAULT= becomes the length of *picture* if you do not give a specific length when you associate the format with a variable.

So, there are a number of options:

Set the default format length to match the expected length of your datetime value (using DEFAULT=12):

```
proc format;
  picture mysdt (default=12)
  low-high = '%Y%0m%0d%0H%0M' (datatype =datetime);
run;
```

Specify the width in your format:

```
DATA _NULL_;
  call symput("Today", strip(Put(datetime(),mysdt12.)));
run;
```

Or, as previously answered, use `call symputx` to trim whitespace:

```
DATA _NULL_;
  call symputx("Today", strip(Put(datetime(),mysdt.)));
run;
```

Personally, I'd fix the format to default to 12, then you won't need to remember to specify width or use `call symputx` each time.

Answer (score 3):

call symputx remove leading and tailing space.

```
DATA _NULL_;
   call symputx("Today", Put(datetime(),mysdt.));
 run;
```